# Why are algebraic cycles rational?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, hodge-theory

Let $X_{/\mathbb{C}}$ be a projective non-singular variety of dimension $n$ and $Z \subset X$ be an irreductible subvariety of dimension $p$.
Denote by $\mathrm{H}_{\mathrm{dR}}^i(X,\mathbb{C})$ the de Rham cohomology of $X(\mathbb{C})$.
By Poincare duality, there is a form $[Z] \in \mathrm{H}_{\mathrm{dR}}^{2n-2p}(X,\mathbb{C})$, such that
$$\int_{X} [Z] \wedge \alpha = \int_{Z} \alpha$$
for all $\alpha \in \mathrm{H}_{\mathrm{dR}}^{2p}(X,\mathbb{C})$.

Denote $\mathrm{H}^{i}(X,\mathbb{Q})$, the singular cohomology with rational coefficients.
Recall that $\mathrm{H}^{i}(X,\mathbb{Q}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C} \simeq \mathrm{H}_{\mathrm{dR}}^i(X,\mathbb{C})$.

> Why is $[Z]$ in $\mathrm{H}^{2n-2p}(X,\mathbb{Q})$?

Comment: Look for "cycle class" in algebraic geometry books: for instance "Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry" by C. Voisin, §11.

Comment: Use Poincare duality over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Did you ever find a satisfying answer to this question? I'm asking myself the same question at the moment.